# How does Google Maps Javascript API V3 usage limits apply to maps on VF pages within Salesforce.com?

Tags: map

Google's details on maps free usage limits are here and seem to imply the 25,000 map loads per day are per API key:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

However, if you place a Google Map on a Visualforce page in Salesforce, even the first load of that page will give you the following error:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The
>   provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized
>   for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site. If you are the
>   owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key
>   here:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

The URL of my page is on a Salesforce Developer Edition org:

https://[my_sf_app_name].na15.visual.force.com

Why am I immediately over quota? Is it because map loads are counted not just per API key but also per IP address of the server or per second level domain name (eg force.com) and all my neighbours on Salesforce.com have already shot through 25K map loads for the day before I run my page?

Comment: To be clear, the requests to the Maps API are coming from the user's browser, NOT from a Salesforce server. This is Google Maps, NOT the Google geocoding service. I'm not sure why IP address sharing among Salesforce orgs on the server should have anything to do with it.

Comment: It certainly could, because even though the Google JS code is executed via the customer's browser, it's very likely sharing its URL and other bits of context with Google (hence the "on this site" phrasing). That would explain the behavior you're seeing. An easy test would be to execute your exact same Google client-side code on some other non-SFDC domain (not localhost), I'd expect it would work as long as your API key is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately many cloud platforms share IP address between different tenants and applications. As you suspect you are probably sharing limits but there are workarounds.

Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127112/how-does-google-geocoding-api-usage-limits-apply-to-salesforce-com